# Facial Expression recognition

Tags: java

I want to do project on Facial Expression Recognition.It will be to detect the expressions of a person using neural networks e.g happy,sad etc.Is it possible in java??

Comment: Yes, this is possible in *any language*. Every algorithm can be implemented in any language; it has really nothing to do with the language. But the problem given is very non-trivial, so do not expect it to be easily solved.

Comment: Voting to close as this is not a real question! The OP clearly has not done any research on this...

Comment: I think it's likely (s)he's asking if there are supporting libraries available in java.

Comment: there are any libraries in java 2 do this project?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start off with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (Open Computer Vision) [bindings for Java](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/). That can make you go through the initial image recognition hoops.

There are some Java Neural Network implementations, here are top two:

- [Neuroph](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/)
- [Encog](http://code.google.com/p/encog-java/)

With this I believe You can get quite far.

Comment: What are the libraries available in java??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java has all the functionality required to create what you're describing -- but you'll have to write your own or find libraries for components like the neural network and a face-detector. Additionally you'll need come up with features (possibly) and have enough data to train your neural network for adequate performance.

Comment: In matlab there are inbuilt functions regarding this project?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to do it in  any language.
Java is nice choice for that.

Check this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java)